# Java subclass no arguments

Tags: java

I have a class called "Card"

```
public class Card
{
  private int cardNumber;
  private String cardName;

  public Card(int cardNumber, String cardName)
  {
     this.cardNumber = cardNumber;
     this.cardName   = cardName;
  }

  public String toString()
  {
     return cardName;
  }

  public int getNumber()
  {
     return cardNumber;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to make a subclass of the Card class called "Ace", but I keep getting the following error whenever I try to compile Ace:
Ace.java:5: error: constructor Card in class Card cannot be applied to given types;

Here's what I have for Ace:

```
public class Ace extends Card
{
   public String isAce;
   public Ace()
   {
   }

   public Ace(int cardNumber, String cardName, String isAce)
   {
      this.cardNumber = cardNumber;
      this.cardName = cardName;
      this.isAce = "yes";
   }
}
```

I don't understand why I am getting the error when I try to compile Ace. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to call the `super()` constructor within your `Ace` class.

Comment: On a side note, why do you have the `isAce` parameter? If the object is an `Ace` object, this seems unnecessary. Also, a `boolean` type would be best for those kinds of parameters anyway.

Comment: You need to actually call a constructor.  Since your only constructor in Card takes arguments, the compiler needs to know which arguments to apply.  You need to tell it which.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Card` has a constructor (so it doesn't get a *`default`* empty constructor). You need to explicitly invoke it in the `Ace` constructor. Like,

```
public Ace(int cardNumber, String cardName, String isAce)
{
    super(cardNumber, cardName);
    this.isAce = "yes";
}
```

Without an explicit invocation of `super()` (or `this()`) the compiler implicitly adds `super()` (with no arguments). That doesn't work here. Because (as I mentioned) `Card` already has a non-empty, non-default constructor.